# Sending messages between two widgets using Signals and Slots

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, signals-slots

I need to have widgets communicating between each other.

My central Widget has 2 widget instances: `widget A` (instance of `A()`), `widget B` (instance of `B()`)
When a `widget A` is subject to an event (e.g.: `mouseRelease`),
I need `widget A` to call *a function* and to do some computing, processing data.
And then I need this processed data *to be passed to* the `widget B`,
which in turn *upon receiving this data* from `widget A`, will call a function with this data, process it, and do something more with it.

Both these widgets are custom widgets derived from `QWidget`. 
I am almost certain I need to use signals and slots but I don't understand how to implement function call parts.

I've read over and over again explanations of Qt here:
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Signals_and_Slots_in_PySide however I can not figure it out how to connect two widgets which both process data emitted and sent.

I would really appreciate some help here. If you can not answer in Python yet competent with C++, please explain nonetheless using it instead of refraining at all.

Comment: can you provide us with some of your code ?? or your are asking how to do signal and slots from the beginning ??

Comment: Hello Ahmed, thank you for checking out my question. I am not asking how to do signals and slots from the beginning ;-). I am just asking, how to connect two widgets which have QMainWindow as their parent. I don't know how can they communicate? I can of course post some code but I am just trying examples from the PyQt page and the link above, the standard basics.

Comment: I can do it using c++(Qt) not PyQt,Is that what you are looking for ??

Comment: Hello again! I would very much like to see an example of any sort. I am currently passing lots of things between objects to achieve this and I believe Signals and Slots is the way to fix it. So if you are able to, I would be very happy to see a simple example.

Comment: I am working on it now :D

Comment: Hey Phil,check my answer , it worked for me on Qt Creator

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a example demonstrating signals/slots connections between two widgets in PyQt4:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class widgetB(QtGui.QWidget):
    procDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetB, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Send Message to A", self)
        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.procDone.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_procStart(self, message):
        self.lineEdit.setText("From A: " + message)

        self.raise_()

class widgetA(QtGui.QWidget):
    procStart = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetA, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText("Hello!")

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Send Message to B", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.procStart.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_widgetB_procDone(self, message):
        self.lineEdit.setText("From B: " + message)

        self.raise_()


class mainwindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtGui.QPushButton("Click Me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        self.widgetA = widgetA()
        self.widgetB = widgetB()

        self.widgetA.procStart.connect(self.widgetB.on_procStart)
        self.widgetB.procDone.connect(self.widgetA.on_widgetB_procDone)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.widgetA.show()
        self.widgetB.show()

        self.widgetA.raise_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app  = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainwindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Hello X.Jacobs. Thank you very much for this excellent answer. It has helped me greatly along others'. I have a much much greater understanding of signals & slots now. Thank you, once again.

Answer (score 9):

Update answer of @user1006989 for PyQt5:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class widgetB(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    procDone = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetB, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send Message to A", self)
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.procDone.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_procStart(self, message):
        self.lineEdit.setText("From A: " + message)

        self.raise_()


class widgetA(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    procStart = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(widgetA, self).__init__(parent)

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setText("Hello!")

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send Message to B", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.procStart.emit(self.lineEdit.text())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def on_widgetB_procDone(self, message):
        self.lineEdit.setText("From B: " + message)

        self.raise_()


class mainwindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(mainwindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Click Me", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.on_button_clicked)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)

        self.widgetA = widgetA()
        self.widgetB = widgetB()

        self.widgetA.procStart.connect(self.widgetB.on_procStart)
        self.widgetB.procDone.connect(self.widgetA.on_widgetB_procDone)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_button_clicked(self):
        self.widgetA.show()
        self.widgetB.show()

        self.widgetA.raise_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = mainwindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use two different approaches here: make the `A` and `B` classes tightly coupled, or using the main-window as mediator.

In the first case you will have to "let `A` know `B`", meaning that `A` has a reference to `B`. In this case you don't even have to do signals & slots at all but you can simply call `B`'s methods directly.

The other approach is to let `A` emit a signal *with an argument* containing the data that should be received by `B`, the main-window catches this signal and calls `B` with the data.
Alternatively you can put the data in an `A`'s attribute and let the main-window take it from here directly, without passing it as signal's argument.

The latter method allows you to write a bit more freely `A` and `B` since `A` does not have to know how to call `B`.

Explained in code it should looks like this:

```
class A(QWidget):
    the_signal = Signal(...)
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.a_function()
        self.the_data = self.produce_data()
        self.the_signal.emit()

class B(QWidget):
    def process_data(self, data):
        pass

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a_widget = A()
        self.b_widget = B()
        self.a_widget.the_signal.connect(self.do_process)
        # if the signal has the data as argument:
        # self.a_widget.the_signal.connect(self.b_widget.process_data)
    def do_process(self):
        self.b_widget.process_data(self.a_widget.the_data)
```

Comment: thank you again and again for all your help and wonderful responses. You're surely one of the life savers in here. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It could be done using several methods , the easiest one (not the most clever) is making intermediate connection, from object A to mainwindows,mainwindow to B

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "classa.h"
#include "classb.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    classA *a;
    classB *b;

signals:
    void TosignalA();
    void TosignalB();

public slots:
    void emitB();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    a = new classA(this);
    b=new classB(this);
    connect(this,SIGNAL(TosignalA()),this->a,SLOT(emitsig()));
    connect(this->a,SIGNAL(signal()),this,SLOT(emitB()));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(TosignalB()),this->b,SLOT(on_signal()));

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::emitB()
{
    emit TosignalB();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    emit TosignalA();
}
```

classa.h

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H
#define CLASSA_H

#include <QObject>

class classA : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit classA(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:
    void signal();

public slots:
    void emitsig();

};

#endif // CLASSA_H
```

classa.cpp

```
#include "classa.h"

classA::classA(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{

}

void classA::emitsig()
{
    emit signal();
}
```

classb.h

```
#ifndef CLASSB_H
#define CLASSB_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtGui>

class classB : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit classB(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void on_signal();

};

#endif // CLASSB_H
```

classb.cpp

```
#include "classb.h"

classB::classB(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent)
{
}
void classB::on_signal()
{
    QMessageBox *msgBox = new QMessageBox();
     msgBox->setText("signal emitted!");
     msgBox->exec();
}
```